# Eclipse treating file as plain text

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, syntax-highlighting

I've got a small homework project, and for whatever reason Eclipse has decided to stop highlighting syntax or allowing intellisense or goto definitions or anything in this Main.java file. I've tried rebooting it, and the computer, but had no luck.

The thing that really has me confused is that it's still compiling and running the code correctly (eg, changes I make in Main.java are compiled and run - it's not running old Main.class files), so it's still in the build path ... right?

Any ideas?

[image: Weird Eclipse situation]

Comment: Are you sure you haven't just opened the file with the Text Editor rather than the Java Editor?

Answer (score 4):

Right click on the file in the Package Explorer and choose the `Open With` menu. You will probably find that `Text Editor` is selected, choose `Java Editor` to open the file with the correct editor.

The Open With menu selection is remembered so you should get the Java Editor in future, but equally if you choose the plain text editor that is also remembered.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest finding a way to reset any setting you might have set by accident. Not saying that you did it. But just to make sure, just try it out. If you customized the preferences already, you could make some kind of note of the settings, then change it. If that doesn't work, let me know. Good Luck!

Comment: Wasn't able to find any altered settings, but I did manage to fix the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Copy the text somewhere, delete the file, and then add a new class (of the same name) and paste the text back.